# Where do the return currents go for a MCU with multiple Vdd and grounds?

Tags: pcb, grounding, layout, ground-loop

I am reading this article on mixed signal design: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5450

When signals have really high speed, the return current will tend to follow right under the signal traces. Let's say a MCU has a SPI module. And power inside MCU is supplying the SPI module. The SPI module is then sourcing currents to an IC through signal trace A.

The return currents from the IC will try to follow right under trace A and go into the SPI module and then go into the power that supplying the SPI module.

The process is shown in the following diagram:
[image: Sourcing currents and return currents]

My question is: if a MCU has multiple Vdds, which power pin does the return current head to? In the following diagram, both pin 19 and pin 48 are Vdd for MCU. Which power pin supplies current for the SPI module?

I ask this question because I think it is highly related with PCB Layouts: where the return currents really go.

[image]

Comment: Power and ground are distributed around the chip and the layout is unknown, so the question is meaningless. Of course, each power pin should be decoupled.

Comment: Hi it is about returning current paths instead of decoupling caps I am thinking about.

Comment: Always use decoupling caps. You don't want to discover, what happens if you don't.

Comment: Many decoupling caps are used. I am asking this question because I may need to split the ground plane. To do this correctly, I need to know more about return currents.

Comment: Why do you want to split the ground plane? Does your MCU have two different kinds of ground pins? What does the datasheet say about the purpose of each kind of ground pin?

Comment: yes, there are two kinds of ground pins, for analog and digital purposes respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't matter.

Every Vdd will have a decoupling cap.

So as your return current follows your signal, it will internally go to whichever power pin has the least impedance, and then go to ground through again, the path of least impedance, which is most likely through the decoupling caps.

So knowing which power pin, doesn't matter. Have decoupling caps, and a ground plane, and the currents will do the rest.

Comment: And be sure, there always is ground or vdd plane under your signal trace, si the current will not look for better path. If your signal travels above void in a plain, the current will go around, but also will radiate, create reflection, etc.

Comment: I am asking because I am to split the ground planes. Knowing more is better I think.

Comment: There is no need to add slits or cuts to the plane if you follow the route that return currents go. Figure 24 in the maxim article, states that the slits can be removed because none of the currents want to cross between analog and digital planes.

Comment: There are complicated situations where slits are helpful, some of them are shown at the bottom of the maxim article.